# angular2+ tslint show 'variable xxx used before declaration' when using forwardRef

Tags: angular, angular6, tslint

i am using 'forwardRef' to write a costom form component. it works but when runing ng lint, shows 'variable FormMultiInputComponent used before declaration'. 
so how to avoid the error?

```
export const EXE_COUNTER_VALUE_ACCESSOR: any = {
  provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
  useExisting: forwardRef(() => FormMultiInputComponent),
  multi: true
};

@Component({
  selector: 'cmss-form-multi-input',
  templateUrl: './form-multi-input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form-multi-input.component.scss'],
  providers: [EXE_COUNTER_VALUE_ACCESSOR]
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix this issue you can set **`"no-use-before-declare": false`** on TSLINT json file

From **[Docs](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-use-before-declare/)**

> This rule is primarily useful when using the var keyword since the
>   compiler will automatically detect if a block-scoped let and const
>   variable is used before declaration. Since most modern TypeScript
>   doesn’t use var, this rule is generally discouraged and is kept around
>   for legacy purposes. It is slow to compute, is not enabled in the
>   built-in configuration presets, and should not be used to inform
>   TSLint design decisions.